# Async IIFE vs. Thenable

Tags: javascript

Immediately-Invoked Function Expression:

```
(async (myVal) => {
  try {
    // stuff
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})(myVal)
```

Thenable:

```
Promise.resolve()
  .then(async (myVal) => {
    // stuff
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

The self-invoked runs quicker. Other than that, any specific advantage to utilize one over the other and in which situations?

Comment: They don't look like the same operation to me. I'm not why you're using `Promise.resolve` in the second example. If you wanted an equivalent operation, you would have to do your `stuff` in `new Promise` instead. The `.then` call is always already async, whereas the `async` function is only executed asyncly at the first `await` statement.

Comment: Using Promise.resolve() is safer than new Promise because any exception thrown within the `then` is converted to a rejected promise, whereas an exception thrown within new Promise is thrown synchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some other differences:

- It looks nicer
- It uses `myVal` instead of `undefined` for the local `myVal` variable
- It's syntax and doesn't rely on the global value of `Promise` or its methods